# low efficiency in mobile phone charger

Tags: power-supply, energy

Looking at my phone charger:

> Model LG MCS-02EP
>
> Input 100-240 V, 50-60 Hz, 0.2A
>
> Output: 5.0 V 0.85 A

That means input power from 20W to 48W and output 4.25 W. Thus, an efficiency in transfer of energy around 10% - 20%, losing up to 90% of the energy. It seems an illogical waste of energy.

I can assume 0.2A has a peak, but then same peak should be mapped to the output or must be consumed by the power adapter itself (when and where?)

Comment: Have you measured what it actually draws with a known load on it?

Comment: @laptop2d: no, I've no "kill a watt"

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption that the adapter actually draws 0.2 A from the mains is simply **WRONG**. What is listed is the **maximum** current.

This is the current that will flow for a **very** short time when you plug the adapter into the mains while mains is at the peak of the sinewave (maximum voltage) and the adapter's smoothing capacitor is completely discharged. Only then 0.2 A will flow **for a fraction of a second**.

If the adapter was really that inefficient it would get **very** hot and I mean so hot that you will not be able to touch it.

Typically these power adapters have an efficiency of around 80% to 90% and not the 10% to 20 % you claim. Your assumption and efficiency calculation is simply wrong.

*but then same peak should be mapped to the output* No it is not, it simply does not work like that. The 0.2 A is a peak value, after initial charge of the smoothing capacitor the mains current will be much lower.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, please, when you quote do it correctly "same peak should be mapped to the output" is false, "same peak should be mapped to the output or must be consumed by the power adapter itself" (the correct quote) is true, being you answer "it is consumed by the capacitor of the power adapter".

Comment: I quoted like that because I had a problem with the *mapped to the output*, there's no reason for that to happen and wanted to emphasize that.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui No, you are overspecifying that statement too. Even without a single capacitor in the adapter the statement would still hold.